# Unable to connect Bluetooth headset with AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord while app is running

Tags: ios, audio, bluetooth, core-audio, avaudiosession

I'm developing a music app that requires input from the microphone, so my `AVAudioSessionCategory` is set to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

I'm trying to get bluetooth headphones working with the app, but I've noticed something peculiar about pairing BT with different `AVAudioSession` categories:

If I use `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`, the BT headphones pair/unpair fine while the app is running or before the app launches. I am able to receive `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`s when pairing or unpairing the headphones also.

With `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` however, I am able to pair and receive audio with BT if I pair it before the app launches, but if I try to pair while the app is running it won't work. My BT headphones will indicate that they are "connected" but the BT icon won't appear on the iOS status bar. I also don't receive any kind of `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`s or other audio interruption notifications while I'm turning the headphones on or off.

I can get BT working if I move the app into the background and then re-enter it, but I can never pair while the app is in the foreground.

I am using libpd for the audio engine, and here is how I initialize my `PdAudioController` object:

```
 [self.pdAudio configurePlaybackWithSampleRate:samplingRate numberChannels:2 inputEnabled:YES mixingEnabled:NO];

 //enable bluetooth
 [PdAudioController setSessionOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP];
```

Is there some other setting I can change to be able to pair headphones while the app is running when using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`?

Comment: Do your BT headphones support recording? Do they have a microphone?

Comment: Yes, they do have a microphone that I can use for calls/recording, but I just did a test and it seems like the BT microphone is not active even if they are paired and sound is being output through the BT headphones (higher input levels are being recorded from the iPhone mic instead of the BT mic). 

Do you think this is related in any way? It doesn't matter to me where the input is being received (my app analyses audio from live musical instruments), but it matters that you cannot pair BT while the app is running, *only* when using `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

Comment: Re the BT microphone, does `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth` help? I'm just guessing, I can't add much - have you tried @hotpaw2's suggestion?

Comment: Using `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth` with libpd causes stuttering audio and clicks, and `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP` does work fine as long as you are already paired with BT before launching the app. This might be something I should be filing an issue with the `libpd` devs because they have not done a lot of testing on this front it seems:

https://github.com/libpd/libpd/issues/177
https://github.com/libpd/libpd/issues/245

Comment: Also, I have tried @hotpaw2's suggestion but I still have the same problem as I never receive a route changed notification when switching on my BT headphones while the app is running.

Comment: Have you tried any other BT devices?

Comment: I have not, but others working on this project have and experienced the same results. I have posted an issue on the `libpd` github to see if the devs can shed any light on this: https://github.com/libpd/libpd/issues/249

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 0):

Many bluetooth headsets seem to be limited to specific sets of sample rates, sometimes not the same rate for input (microphone) and output (speaker).  So they can't connect to a live audio session that has incompatible sample rates.

When an apps stops its audio session to go to the background, and later re-enters the foreground, this gap allows the Audio Session and Audio Unit code to re-negotiate the sample rates (e.g. suggest, and handle failure/error codes, -50, etc.) before (re)enabling the session and (re)starting the audio unit.

If you get a route change notification, you could try having the app stop audio, tear down its session, wait a few ticks, and then restart any audio as needed.

Comment: Funnily enough, I am switching off audio in my route changed notification, reconfiguring the audio unit to play at the preferred sampling rate based on what is connected, and then switching audio back on. However the weird thing is that the route changed notification never gets sent when I'm turning on my headset while the app is running. If I am already connected with BT before launching the app, I *will* receive the notification when switching off BT while the app is running.

Comment: hmmm... Apps might not be getting notifications for devices incompatible with the current session?  You might have to let the user (the few who read app documentation) manually switch.